# How to have www.site.com and site.com with Orchard Multi-Tenancy module

Tags: orchardcms

I have successfully set up multi-tenancy in Orchard on a public facing site. If you enter www.tenant.com it works fine in Orchard. However, Orchard's admin for Tenants only allows input for one site. In the instance where a user just types tenant.com, when I tried binding that in landlord site it takes me to the landlord page, not the tenant. Adding a new "tenant" in Orchard Tenants admin will literally create a new site (at least, i get to the setup recipe page) and not take that alternative to the actual tenant site. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question. What I would do is put a permanent redirect from one of the domains to the one you prefer to be canonical. From an SEO perspective, that's what you should do anyway.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. For those looking into this: in IIS on the server which holds Orchard, go to the directory for the TENANT site, click the link for HTTP Redirect in the Features view for that TENANT site. Check "Redirect requests to this destination" and input the http:// with the www and the dot and the TENANT name dot com (sorry, not letting me input) (replacing TENANT with your Tenant site's name). Do not check off any redirect behavior. Now, www.TENANT.com and TENANT.com entered into browser will both bring you to your Tenant's site.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry to bump a really old question but I am bored and am reading through some Orchard source code and I see this:

```
_shellsByHost = qualified
            .SelectMany(s => s.RequestUrlHost == null || s.RequestUrlHost.IndexOf(',') == -1 ? new[] {s} : 
                s.RequestUrlHost.Split(new [] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Select(h => new ShellSettings(s) {RequestUrlHost = h}))
            .GroupBy(s => s.RequestUrlHost ?? string.Empty)
            .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key.Length);
```

I don't actually have any multi-tenant sites to test this on and am too lazy to set one up but well, looks to me like you can just do "www.test.com, test.com". Maybe someone can clarify this but I think this would be the simplest solution for anyone else encountering this problem.

All the best